# Bundle import configuration file without using app/config

Tags: symfony

I would like to configure mybundle config file, not in the symfony2 one.

Currently, I have this in my `config/config.yml` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine_config.yml" }
```

But it means that my Bundle can be unusable if we don't add manually this lines in the config. How can I import the additional configuration without manually importing it to the config file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to say to your bundle to load it like this

```
class YourBundleExtension extends Extension
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) 
{
    // ...
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('doctrine_config.yml');
}
```

(this file already exist, in your DependencyInjection folder)